# Regex for Password strength with additional rules on first character

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I need a regex for password strength which has 3 different rules:

1. Minimum 3 out of 4 groups (lowercase, uppercase, number, special character)
2. Minimum 8 character
3. First character not '{' (some product restriction where this is implemented)

So far I have a regex which achieves the first two rules. Additionally I was able to extend the regex to limit the first character. However my current issue is, that when I limit the first character it is not considered in regard to the first rule. E.g. The following password does not pass: $MyPassword

Initial rule: `^((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])).{8,}$`

Extended rule: `^[^{]{1}((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])).{8,}$`

Since I'm still a bit lost with regular expressions, I would appreciate a solution including some explanations.

Thanks in advance!

Note: I'll use this regex in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, you should put in a negative assertion on the `{` in the front instead of a non-matching character. That lets you enter any character and does not count for the assertion which will mess up all of your rules.

This would be your regex:
`^(?=[^\{])((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])).{8,}$`

If you want to know what you are doing, please look into [this article](https://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/) that explains assertions. It will make a lot more clear about the `(?=` usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot works like a charm! And thanks for the article it's a very good introduction to positive lookaheads.